# Помогите расставить запятые. Просьба пояснить.

Tags: пунктуация

Уроженец Омской области, маршал Советского Союза, министр Обороны СССР, Дмитрий Тимофеевич Язов отмечал свой 90-летний юбилей.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Все запятые, кроме последней, указаны верно. По правилам приложение стоящее непосредственно перед именем собственном не обособляется.
```

**Обновление**

Наименования ученых степеней и званий, почетные звания, названия должностей выступают в общем ряду как однородные приложения. Напр.: директор Института внешней торговли, кандидат технических наук, доцент И. М. Лебедев. (Трудные случаи пунктуации. Д.Э. Розенталь. Белинский).

Comment: Спасибо! Поняла.

Answer (score 0):

Запятые не нужны, так как эти приложения неоднородные.